# using jquery plugin to make two td from diffrent table sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

hi i am making an UI in which i thought of using a zepto plugin [zepto plugin](https://github.com/zakj/html5sortable)

for making two 'td' element from diffrent table sortable but in that i have a problem that this plugin is working fine for `<li>` element and while using for `<td>` element its not working can anyone please tell if it is possible to use this plugin for `<td>` element or if you have some other plugin which i can use
this is my html code

```
 <div id="fool">
  <table ="sortable list">
    <tr >
       <td draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">english</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
       <td draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">hindi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td  draggable="true"style="background-color:green">maths</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
       <td  draggable="true"style="background-color:white">physics</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

and this is the code using for javascript

```
 $('.sortable').sortable();
```

if anyone could help if it will be very helpful thanks in advance

Comment: you missed class in `="sortable list"`

Comment: actually that plugin require only .sortable

Comment: change `="sortable list"` to `class="sortable list"`

Comment: done but still no luck the td is dragging but other td are disapearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out myself and came to the conclusion it does not work properly for table elements `<td>`, just for lists `<ul>`. As it is `sort able` and not `sort table`

this works:

```
<div id="fool">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">english</li>
    <li draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">hindi</li>
    <li draggable="true" style="background-color:green">maths</li>
    <li draggable="true" style="background-color:white">physics</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xqka18m1/

Comment: thanks for that but i really want two 'td' element to be sortable i tried it with two different 'div' its working now i want the two 'td' element from this two 'div' to be sortable

Comment: You can recreate a table with div's, so now is the question why that's not enough

Comment: yes even if i create a div i want my data to be in tabular form as it is representing a time table

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/using-the-div-tag-to-create-tables.html just make it `look like` a table

Comment: even if i make it look like table i will have same problem as sortable-list class have to be given in parent class and only immediate child can be  sortable